# Rails 5 inverse_of join table doesn't want to work with deeply nested Cocoon fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, cocoon-gem

I am using `Ruby 2.6.5` and `Rails 5.2.3`. I have a form with double nested objects with **Cocoon**. The form is for `Preorders`. A `Preorder` can have many `Dancers`. `Dancers` can have many and belong to many `Groups`, so I set up a **join table** called `DancerGroup`.

I use **Cocoon** to add `dancers_attributes` to the `Preorder` form, and again to add `dancer_groups_attributes` inside of the `dancers_attributes` fields.

*My problem* is that when I attempt to save a `Preorder` with a new `Dancer` and new `DancerGroup` associations I get the following error:

> - Dancers dancer groups dancer can't be blank

Which clearly means it's trying to save the `dancer_group` object before the `dancer` record has an `id` The obvious answer is that since I'm using Rails 5, the `belongs_to` association is required by default, and the work around is to properly use `inverse_of` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` methods to let Rails manage saving everything all at once. *But it's not working* when it comes to my **join table**. I even get the same error when I set `optional: true` on the `belongs_to :dancer` in the `DancerGroup` model.

My **strong params** look like this:

```ruby
private
  def preorder_params
    params.require(:preorder).permit( :event_id,
                                      :dancers_attributes => [
                                        :_destroy,
                                        :id,
                                        :name,
                                        :dancer_groups_attributes => [
                                          :_destroy,
                                          :group_id,
                                          :id ]
                                        ] 
                                      )
  end
```

My **models** look like this:

*app/models/preorder.rb*

```ruby
class Preorder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :dancers, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :preorder 
  has_many :dancer_groups, through: :dancers, dependent: :destroy

  with_options reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true do
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dancers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dancer_groups
  end

  validates :dancers, :length => { minimum: 1 }
  ...
end
```

*app/models/dancer.rb*

```ruby
class Dancer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :preorder, counter_cache: true, inverse_of: :dancers
  has_many :dancer_groups, inverse_of: :dancer, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: dancer_groups

  with_options reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true do
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dancer_groups
  end
  ...
end
```

*app/models/dancer_group.rb*

```ruby
class DancerGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dancer, inverse_of :dancer_groups
  belongs_to :group, inverse_of :dancer_groups
  ...
end
```

And here's what my **form files** look like

*views/admin/preorders/_form.html.haml*

```
...
%fieldset
  %legend Dancers
  #dancers
    - @preorder.dancers.each do |dancer|
      = f.fields_for :dancers, dancer do |ff|
        = render "dancer_fields", f: ff, preorder: @preorder
    = link_to_add_association f, :dancers,
        { "data-association-insertion-node": "#dancers",
          "data-association-insertion-method": "append",
        render_options: { locals: { preorder: @preorder } },
        class: "btn btn-info btn-sm btn-simple float-right" } do 
      = icon "fas", "plus"
      Add Dancer
...
```

*views/admin/preorders/_dancer_fields.html.haml*

```
...
.card.preorder_dancer
  .card-header.row
    .col
      %h4.card-title Dancer Info
    .col-auto
      = link_to_remove_association f, { wrapper_class: "preorder_dancer",
          class: "btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-simple btn-danger" } do 
        = icon "fas", "times"
  .card-body
    .row.pb-3
      .col 
        = f.label :name do 
          Full Name
          %span.text-danger *
        = f.text-field :name, class: "form-control"
    %h4.card-title Dance Groups
    .row{ :id => "dancer_groups_#{f.object.id}" }
      - f.object.dancer_groups.each do |dancer_group|
        = f.fields_for :dancer_groups, dancer_group do |ff|
          = render "dancer_group_fields, f: ff, 
                                  preorder: preorder
    =link_to_add_association f, :dancer_groups,
      { "data-association-insertion-node": "#dancer_groups_#{f.object.id}",
        "data-association-insertion-method": "append",
        render_options:  {locals: { preorder: preorder } },
        class: "btn btn-info btn-sm btn-simple float-right" } do
      =icon "fas", "plus"
      Add Dance Group
```

*views/admin/preorders/_dancer_group_fields.html.haml*

```
.col-lg-6.preorder_dancer_group
  .card.bg-dark
    .card-header.row
      .col
        %h4.card-title Dance Group
      .col.text-right
        =link_to_remove_association f, { wrapper_class: "preorder_dancer_group",
                                    class: "btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-simple btn-danger"} do
          =icon "fas", "times"
    .card-body
      .row
        .col
          =f.label :group_id do
            Group
            %span.text-danger *
          =f.collection_select :group_id,
                               preorder.event.groups,
                               :id,
                               :name,
                               {include_blank: "Select Group"},
                               {class: "form-control"}
```

Comment: In the `Dancer`  model, you have `has_many :dancer_groups, through: :dancers` and afaik that should be just `has_many :dancer_groups`, right? I hope that also solves your problem?

Comment: @nathanvda it should have said `inverse_of:` instead of `through:` Fixed it.

Comment: You say "fixed it", so this does or does not fix the problem? or did you just correct the typo? Because this would explain the error imho.

Comment: Corrected the typo. Did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `_dancer_fields` partial you write

```
%h4.card-title Dance Groups
.row{ :id => "dancer_groups_#{f.object.id}" }
  - f.object.dancer_groups.each do |dancer_group|
    = f.fields_for :dancer_groups, dancer_group do |ff|
      = render "dancer_group_fields, f: ff, 
                              preorder: preorder
```

and that should be

```
%h4.card-title Dance Groups
.row{ :id => "dancer_groups_#{f.object.id}" }
  = f.fields_for :dancer_groups do |ff|
    = render "dancer_group_fields, f: ff, 
                              preorder: preorder
```

Because otherwise you are not making the dancer-group "connected" to the dancer.

Comment: I've just tried this. I've removed the `-f.object.dancer_groups.each` line from `_dancer_fields.html.haml`. It didn't work. I also removed the `- @preorder.dancers.each do |dancer|` line from `_form.html.haml` Neither one solved the problem.

Comment: Mmmmm weird. Do you have a minimal github repo that reproduces this problem, so I can check it out?

Comment: I don't, I'm afraid, and it'll be a few weeks before I can put one together.